# org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient Bootstrap broker (id: -3 rack: null) disconnected when connecting to kafka consumer via NiFi

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, aws-msk

I am trying to consume messages from a kafka topic on Amazon MSK (Kafka Version 2.2.1) using NiFi ConsumeKafka_2_6 processor (NiFi version 1.12.1).In ConsumeKafka processor I am getting the warning as "***org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient [Consumer clientId=console-consumer-34567-5, groupId=nifi-consumer] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected***".What can be the cause of this issue?Is this due to version mismatch of kafka client used or due to connectivity issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From aws cli we use the JVM truststore to talk to the MSK cluster. So from NiFi application also I was supposed to use that. I have configured the security protocol as SSL and configured JVM truststore in SSLContextService. Then I was able to consume messages from Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

It's a connectivity problem or you configured the Nifi processor incorrectly

You're not connecting to MSK, you're trying to connect Nifi to itself

> Bootstrap broker localhost:9092

Also, yes, you might have some issues using the 2_6 consumer with a 2.2 cluster, but very minor as the core functions should still work

Comment: I am connecting to MSK cluster only I have given the ip address as local host here. In the logs bootstrap server is shown.

Comment: Okay, then next step would be to check your VPC and firewall rules. Is Nifi running in the same VPC, region, etc?

Comment: NiFi is running on same VPC as MSK cluster.Also  I can  connect to MSK from ec2 host on which NiFi is installed. The issue occurs when trying to connect from NiFi application.How can I troubleshoot?

Comment: As long as you use the same `bootstrap.server` setting in the processor as `kafka-console-consumer`, for example, on the same host, it should work the same

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reason leading to this error. In my case, AWS MSK IAM auth enabled, I was missing the client.properties file while running kafka-console-consumer.sh script `--consumer.config path/to/client.properties`